# SQL Constraint for Canada Postal Code + US Zip Code?

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g, regexp-like

I've created a constraint for Canadian postal code and it works fine, however when I input a US zip code like `1234567`, the record still gets added in. I'm looking for a way to change my constraint so it only accepts `5` *numbers* ?

```
Postal_Code varchar2(7) Constraint NN_Investor_PostalCode Null,
Constraint CK_Investor_PostalCode check 
(REGEXP_LIKE (Postal_Code, '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]') 
    or REGEXP_LIKE (Postal_Code, '[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')),
```

Comment: US post codes can also be in the format 99999-9999 (called zip+4).  Make sure you take that into account.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_Code

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
REGEXP_LIKE (Postal_Code, '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]') 
        or ( REGEXP_LIKE (Postal_Code, '^[1-9][0-9]{4}') and length(Postal_Code)=5
```

as the *check* constraint.

*Sample demonstration :*

```
with t(Postal_Code) as
(
 select '12345'   from dual union all
 select '32045'   from dual union all 
 select '1234567' from dual union all
 select '123456'  from dual union all
 select  '01234'  from dual 
)
select * 
  from t
 where REGEXP_LIKE (Postal_Code, '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]') 
    or ( REGEXP_LIKE (Postal_Code, '^[1-9][0-9]{4}') and length(Postal_Code)=5 );

POSTAL_CODE
----------- 
  12345
  32045
```